# Minecraft No Pickaxe

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have been playing Minecraft and when I try to craft a pickaxe it won't show up on the left side. I have installed no mods and have restarted my computer and the game many times and it still won't show up. Is there something wrong with my game? I also looked up how to craft one and its an ingot at top and 2 sticks coming down the center. It used to work but now it doesn't.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the materials you're putting into the crafting table?

Answer (score 3):

It's not how you described.

> I also looked up how to craft one and its an ingot at top and 2 sticks coming down the center. It used to work but now it doesn't.

It's three ingots on the first row, and two sticks on the middle (2nd/3rd rows), as seen here:

[image]

Comment: On a side note, the method you described is the method for the Shovel

Comment: Thats how sorry for bad description

Comment: It’s ok. Plus, it shows up on the right, not the left.